# Notepad ++ add text in end of line with matching two strings

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

if lines start with `NEW` and contains `/` then need to add at end `-reg`.

current:

```
NEW  /RAM
VFXV RAM
NEW /TEST
SDFSDF
DSFDSF
NEW RAM
```

expected:

```
NEW  /RAM-reg
VFXV RAM
NEW /TEST-reg
SDFSDF
DSFDSF
NEW RAM
```

Comment: What about 2 or more slashes in a line, like: `NEW /RAM /TEST`

Answer (score 0):

This will match all lines that begin with NEW and have a slash somewhere in the line.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `^NEW\b.*/.*\K$`
- Replace with: `-reg`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of string
  NEW\b     : literally "NEW", followed by a word boundary to not match NEWLY
  .*/.*     : at least a slash in the line
  \K        : forget all we have seen until this position
$           : end of string
```

**Result for given example:**

```
NEW  /RAM-reg
VFXV RAM
NEW /TEST-reg
SDFSDF
DSFDSF
NEW RAM
```